# How can I collect the output from CI?

Tags: continuous-integration, teamcity

I don't know how to collect the data from each build machine on CI. (I use TeamCity for CI and this is the first time to use CI by myself.)

After building code and running the .exe file, an output file is generated. It is a .csv file and its size is less than 1KB and very simple. I want to collect the data to one place and do some statistics.

The build and running .exe file is working fine. However, I don't know the next step. I have two ideas.

(Idea 1) Set-up a log database server (e.g. kibana-elastic search) and send the output to it. However, it seems an overkilling solution.

(Idea 2) Create a batch file and just copy the log to somewhere.

However, I don't know what is a usual way to use CI and collect the data. I guess there will be a better solution. Is there any way to collect the data by using CI?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can suggest using [build artifacts](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/Build+Artifact): you can configure your builds so that they will produce and make some files available for the users of Teamcity. Then you can download them and analyze as you need. Taking into account that files are pretty small, I think it's an ideal variant.

If you need to collect all artifacts from every build, you can configure another build, which would run some python script, which in turn would utilize Teamcity [REST API](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/REST+API) to collect all artifacts from specific build and zip and produce complete set of your files.

As an example you can check [some](https://teamcity.jetbrains.com/viewType.html?buildTypeId=IdeaVim_Deploy) build at JetBrains test server: just select finished build and navigate to Artifacts tab.

Please ask more questions if my answer is not clear enough.

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed answer. I visited the webpage of build artifacts and this perfectly matches my objective. I will also try REST API. Thank you!